# How would I make an sql MVC query pertaining to 3 tables with if and @@ logic?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC 4. My tables are set up like this

`Computer` table-----

```
[key]  
(int) ComputerID   
(String) ComputerName  
(String) Department
```

`Ticket` table----

```
[key]  
(int) TicketID
[foreign key]  
(int) ComputerID  
(datetime) DownTimeStamp  
(int) runningStatus
```

`Update ticket` table---

```
[key]  
(int) UpdateID  
[foreign key]  
(int) TicketID  
(datetime) updateTimeStamp
```

When a ticket is created, the ticket running status is set to 1, for computer is down

I update the tickets running status every time there is an update with radio buttons, 2 computer restarted, 3 waiting for parts and 4 Maintenance is on site.

I have an index view of the current tickets that refreshes every minute, displaying all the computers that are currently down.

I have a query that joins the 3 tables, my question is, how do I make a query that includes all of the tickets but have a condition that if the running status is set to 2, keep that ticket for only 2 minutes after the update timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you need look like this:

```
var tickets = _db.Tickets
 .Where(x => !(x.runningStatus == 2 && 
               DateTime.Now.Subtract(t.DownTimeStamp).Seconds >= 2 *60));
```

If it isn't what you want, please give some example or describe the question in more detail.